# Covariance and stationarity

Tags: statistics

In my Time Series Analysis class, we state that when the covariance only depends on its lag, the stochastic process is stationary. The thing that I don´t understand is that when we say that, it implies that the mean and the variance are constant (doesn't depend on $t$). What is the relationship between these two things?

Comment: The variance is the covariance for lag $0$ hence one recovers it but the means are entirely unrelated to the covariances hence there is no way to deduce anything about the means, for example that they are constant, from the covariances only.

Comment: Are you sure about that? From the wiki entry on stationary processes, "Consequently, parameters such as mean and variance, if they are present, also do not change over time"